# How to get all vertices of all incoming/outgoing edges from a vertex scala gremlin

Tags: graph-databases, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I have a vertex A -> B . I have multiple outgoing/incoming edges created between these two edges with same label.

When i query to get the neighbour vertex ,it is giving me duplicate vertex for each edges it has to the other vertex.

example :

```
gremlin> graph.traversal().V().has('ID', 'a').both("interference")
==>v[2]
==>v[2]
==>v[2]
==>v[2]
==>v[2]
==>v[2]
```

http://gremlinbin.com/bin/view/58087f51ba0d5

I do not need the duplicate vertex if it has multiple edges .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what the [`dedup()`](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#dedup-step) step is for:

```
gremlin> graph.traversal().V().has('ID', 'a').both("interference").dedup()
==>v[2]
```